# why browser rerenders when I'm inside function paused on debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js

I'm debugging my code. I put debugger to a function which removes items from an array:

```
if (matchFound) {
    debugger
    vm.spots.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
}
```

I'm using knockout and vm.spots is an observableArray, so whenever it changes knockout renders new array. What is weird as that as soon as I passed the line which removes item I can seen Chrome rerendering changes (removing item) while I'm still in a debug mode - the code is paused. How is that possible if browser does its job only when code is not being executed?

Comment: I believe a browser will update the DOM as soon as it's been told to - in this case knockout is adjusting things to suit the new contents of the array as soon as it happens.  Imagine if the next line of code happened to query the height of the rendered array, but it hadn't yet been rendered...

Comment: Updating DOM and rendering is not the same thing. It indeed probably updates DOM as soon as it's told but it can't render it until script is being executed. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udcL8b9q/1/), `text` is not shown while function is being executed.

Comment: Interesting.  With [a change](http://jsfiddle.net/vw1kfe0b/1/) to match your example, it appears as soon as it stops in the debugger.  I guess chrome must render/paint when the scripts are paused, treating it as "code not being executed, so I can re-render"

Comment: Yeah, it could be so. Thanks for your commments! I didn't noticed that behavior earlier though when debugging other scripts - the DOM wasn't rerendered until I let go of debugger and code finished execution.